# SAP B1 determine ObjectType Code for table

Tags: sapb1

I already create a User Table (name= ORN_TB1_VIDS) with single fields like (id,name,rented) so I'm trying to make a ChooseFromList to display my table (ORN_TB1_VIDS) but I don't know what is the correct ObjectType Code for my table .

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the User Tables doesn't have ObjectType, you must have to create an UDO (User Defined Object) an assign it an Object Type